# how does jQuery implement get elements by class name?

Tags: jquery, css, dom

There is no such a "getElementsByClass" function in javascript,

then how does jQuery manage to do that?

Looping all elements will be too less efficient.

BTW,how to specify css to elements with two or more classes?

```
<a class="one two">test</a>
```

Guessing like below?

```
.one.two {...}
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

The [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) function exists, jQuery uses it internally if available, check the [selector.js](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/tags/1.3.2/src/selector.js) file on the jQuery source

To select elements with multiple classes use the [.class.class](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/class#.class.class) selector:

```
$('.one.two')
```

Comment: Is ".one.two" and ".two.one" the same thing?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same, it will find elements with both classes.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses the [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) selector engine.